# Angular:Mat-tree - how to select all checkbox during initial load

Tags: checkbox, treeview, angular16

As ngxtreeview is obsolete in Angular 16+, we are now looking into mat-tree.

After data is loaded in the mat-tree, based on business rules, we need to set the default checked for few of the nodes, it can be a parent(s) or few children from the given parent(s).

https://stackblitz.com/angular/gabkadkvybq?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts

We were looking into above example, but we are not very much sure on how can i set default checked values here

If we look at the requirement, it's basic one, so it might be that i am missing something here.